# consider subquery of the same table in materialized view creation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good afternoon,

how can I edit my select to avoid subquery error message inside materialized view.

> ORA-22818 subquery expressions not allowed here

```
create materialized view vista1
refresh complete on demand
as

select f1.codigo,f1.Car,f1.codCard,f1.descripcion,f1.caracteristicas,
  f1.razonsocial
  f1.codigoAbs,
  f1.codigoCarAbs,
  (select ff.Car 
   from persona ff 
   where ff.codigo=f1.codigoabs 
     and ff.codCard=f1.codigoCarAbs 
     and rownum=1) as "absorbed reference"
from persona f1
```

The logic of the table and columns is as follows:

the "persona" table has columns that identify other people who were absorbed or are under guardianship,these columns are:

-`codeABS` y `codigoCarABS`

- I cannot edit the structure of the tables or create others.

description:

1-the "codigo" field is the primary key of the "persona" table.

2-the "codCard" field is a unique code of the "persona" table.

3-the "codeABS" field, indicates the code of the "persona" who was absorbed, it belongs to a code from the same "persona" table.

4-the "codigoCarABS" field, indicates the CAR code of the "persona" who was absorbed, it belongs to a code from the same "persona" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a join?

```
SELECT f1.codigo,
       f1.car,
       f1.codcard,
       f1.descripcion,
       f1.caracteristicas,
       f1.razonsocial,
       f1.codigoabs,
       f1.codigocarabs,
       f2.car AS absorbed_reference
FROM persona f1
JOIN persona f2 ON f1.codigo = f2.codigoabs AND f1.codigocarabs = f2.codcard;
```

`ROWNUM = 1` you used implies that there might be 2 or more rows; I believe that "my" query then misses the `where` clause which would make sure that only one value from `f2` is fetched. Is there some timestamp column, ordinal number, ... that helps with that? If not and you don't really care which value to return, you could apply e.g. `MIN` function to `f2.car` and put the rest of selected columns into the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT f1.codigo,
       f1.car,
       f1.codcard,
       f1.descripcion,
       f1.caracteristicas,
       f1.razonsocial,
       f1.codigoabs,
       f1.codigocarabs,
       MIN(f2.car)AS absorbed_reference
FROM persona f1
JOIN persona f2 ON f1.codigo = f2.codigoabs
                   AND f1.codigocarabs = f2.codcard
GROUP BY f1.codigo,
         f1.car,
         f1.codcard,
         f1.descripcion,
         f1.caracteristicas,
         f1.razonsocial,
         f1.codigoabs,
         f1.codigocarabs;
```